# How to send variable in component.ts to service.ts for authentication Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to get auth_token from backend and use it in service class. The LoginComponent successfully sends user credentials and receives auth_token (verified through console.log). But I do not know how to use auth_token variable from component into the service class to put it in HttpHeaders.

I have a basic login html. My login.component.ts looks like this:

```html
import { LoginService } from './../../service/login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Login } from './../../model/login';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  login: Login;

  constructor(private service: LoginService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.login = new Login();
  }

  sendLoginCredentials(){
    this.service.authorizeUser(this.login)
    .subscribe((data)=>{
      this.login.auth_token = data.auth_token;
      console.log(this.login.auth_token);
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    })
  }

}
```

The page redirects to home and I get a auth_token back. I have verified this through Postman and console.log(). Now I need to use this auth_token in Angular HttpHeaders in a different service class. Here is my department.service.ts to request a list of departments:

```html
import { Login } from './../model/login';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Department } from '../model/department';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

const URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DepartmentService {
  login: Login = new Login();

  httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    // Authorization: 'token 856f5464e0508620d4cb90d546817e201419a70e',
    Authorization: 'token ' + this.login.auth_token,
  });

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAllDepartments(): Observable<Department[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(URL + 'department-list/', { headers: this.httpHeaders })
      .map((resp) => resp as Department[]);
  }
}
```

The app works if I use hard coded value (in comments) but it gives me "token undefined" in Request Headers. I am not too experienced in Angular so I am stuck here.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use session instead of class for storing "auth_token"

```
sessionStorage.setItem("AuthToken", JSON.stringify(data.auth_token));
```

and whenever you use just get from session and use it like:

```
let authValue = sessionStorage.getItem("AuthToken");

httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'token ' + authValue,
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to interceptor 
by interceptor you can set token in httpHeader
```

for example:

> import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'; import {HttpRequest,
> HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor} from '@angular/common/http';
> import {Observable} from 'rxjs'; import {AuthService} from
> '@core/authentication';
>
> @Injectable() export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
>
> ```
> constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
> }
>
> intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
>     const token = this.authService.getToken() ;
>     if (token !== '') {
>         const authReq = request.clone({
>             setHeaders: {
>                 Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
>             }
>         });
>         return next.handle(authReq);
>     } else {
>     return next.handle(request);
>     }
>
>
> } }
> ```